# React Alert Component close button self close

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an alert react component which uses bootstrap classes.

Here is the component code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Alert extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
          <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
          {this.props.text}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Alert;
```

It works fine but my question is...

How do I get the Alert to self hide when I click on the close button in it?

Comment: Use state to manipulate the display behaviour. setTimeout function to change state

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can do it internally with state:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Alert extends Component {

  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
    this.state = {
      isActive: true,
    }
  }

  hideAlert() {
    this.setState({
      isActive: false,
    });
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.isActive) {
      return (
          <div
            className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible"
            role="alert"
          >
            <button
              type="button"
              className="close"
              data-dismiss="alert"
              aria-label="Close"
              onClick={() => this.hideAlert()}
            >
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
            {this.props.text}
          </div>
      );
    }
    return <div/>
  }
}

export default Alert;
```

Answer (score 0):

I updated **AppsWithHeart's** code with **d.lime's** suggestion. If there is a shorter way (or easier way) of making the if statement, send a comment.

```
import React from "react";

function Alert() {
  const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = React.useState(false);

  const toggleShowInfoPopup = () => {
    setShowPopup(!showPopup);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {(() => {
        if (!showPopup) {
          return (
            <div className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
              <button
                type="button"
                className="close"
                data-dismiss="alert"
                aria-label="Close"
                onClick={toggleShowInfoPopup}
              >
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
              </button>
              Test
            </div>
          );
        }
      })()}
    </>
  );
}

export default Alert;
```

Answer (score -1):

i know this question is not from this year, but as i found it, there might be more people looking for it.

So, i did it as a functional component with a hook. I am still a beginner on this field, so feel free to point me out on sth - so we can learn together :)

EDIT: Here you can toggle the popup, if you just wish to close it you can use the setShowPopup function to not toggle, but set it to false - whatever you need.

Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react';

function Alert() {
    const [showPopup, setShowPopup] = React.useState(false);

const toggleShowInfoPopup = () => {
    setShowPopup(!showPopup);
  };

return (
  <div>
    <div className="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      <button 
        type="button" 
        className="close" 
        data-dismiss="alert" 
        aria-label="Close"
        onClick={toggleShowInfoPopup}
        >
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      {this.props.text}
    </div>
  </div>
);
}

export default Alert;
```

Comment: There is a typo `OnClick={toggleShowPopup}` should be `OnClick={toggleShowInfoPopup}`

Comment: You should also render based on the value of `showPopup` otherwise the toggle won't work